# Is the odd part of even almost perfect numbers (other than the powers of two) not almost perfect?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of the divisors of $x$.  A number $M$ is called **almost perfect** if $\sigma(M) = 2M - 1$.

If $M$ is an **even almost perfect number**, then the only known examples for $M$ are $M = 2^k$, where $k \geq 1$.  (Since $\sigma(1) = 2\cdot{1} - 1$, $1$ is an **odd almost perfect** and is currently the only known such number.)

Antalan and Tagle (in a 2004 preprint titled *Revisiting forms of almost perfect numbers*) show that, if $N \neq 2^k$ is an even almost perfect number, then $N$ takes the form $N = {2^r}{b^2}$ where $r \geq 1$ and $b$ is an odd composite.  We call $b^2$ the **odd part** of the even almost perfect number $N$.

Since $N$ is almost perfect, we have
$$(2^{r+1} - 1)\sigma(b^2) = \sigma(2^r)\sigma(b^2) = \sigma({2^r}{b^2}) = \sigma(N) = 2N - 1 = {2^{r+1}}b^2 - 1.$$

So we have
$$\sigma(b^2) = \frac{{2^{r+1}}b^2 - 1}{2^{r+1} - 1} = b^2 + \frac{b^2 - 1}{2^{r+1} - 1}.$$

Now,
$$2b^2 - \sigma(b^2) = b^2 -\frac{b^2 - 1}{2^{r+1} - 1}.$$

If the odd part $b^2$ is also almost perfect, then we have
$$1 = 2b^2 - \sigma(b^2) = b^2 -\frac{b^2 - 1}{2^{r+1} - 1},$$
which, since $b > 1$, gives
$$2^{r+1} - 1 = 1 \Longleftrightarrow r = 0.$$

This contradicts $r \geq 1$.

Consequently, since $b^2$ is deficient, we can write $\sigma(b^2) = 2b^2 - c$, where $c > 1$. (We then call $b^2$ a $c$-**deficient number**.)

My question is:  Is this proof correct?

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: @mathlove, please write out your last comment as an actual answer below, so that I may be able to accept it (and so that the question does not remain unanswered!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this proof correct?

I have not found any errors in your proof, so it looks correct to me.